# Using IS operator to identify the type of Form

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to write a common method which would check if a form is already open. If it is open then just activate it. Otherwise show it. Now my challenge is what type of parameter do I pass to the Test method?

```
private void Test(?? ??)
        {
            bool isFormOpen = false;
            foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (form is ??)
                {
                    isFormOpen = true;
                    form.Activate();
                }
            }
            if (!isFormOpen)
            {

            }
        }
```

Thanks
 Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way your code is written you need to pass [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) of the respective Form class...

```
           if (form.GetType() == theTypeParam)
            {
                isFormOpen = true;
                form.Activate();
            }
```

An alternative is to use generice - see [the answer from Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180111/847363) for that.

Comment: can you please show me the code briefly? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are basically passing a type, you could make the method generic:

```
private void ActivateIfOpen<T>() 
{ 
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) 
    { 
        bool isFormOpen = false; 
        if (form is T)
        {
            isFormOpen = true; 
            form.Activate(); 
        }
    } 
    ...
}

// call like this
ActivateIfOpen<MyMainForm>();
```

Answer (score 4):

I would go with something like

```
    private void Test<TForm>()
       where TForm : Form
    {
        TForm form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (form != null)
        {

        }
     }
```

Comment: If two or more instances of same form type is open, does this code work as expected?

Comment: if 2 or more it would throw an exception, but that was the behaviour I decided the user wanted as he says that if it is already open the activate it, if not then create it. It seems as if he is using this as a guard to ensure only one instance of a form is open.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Generic method like this:

```
private static void Test<T>()
    where T : Form
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f is T)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

or you can pas the Type of a form to the method

```
private static void Test(Type formType)
{
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (f.GetType() == formType)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is that Application.OpenForms also has a `index[string name]` parameter. So if you don't want to use the type to identify a form you can also identify it by name by using: `Application.OpenForms["myFormName"]`

Answer (score 0):

In both solutions the result is that if there are more windows of the same class, all these windows are opened.